# spotify api php show user details in redirect

Tags: php, spotify

I am using the spotify api and [this php library](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php).

I have created an app in the spotify dev portal, with a redirect url. This is all working fine.

My Spotify API code looks like this:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session(
    'CLIENT_ID',
    'CLIENT_SECRET',
    'index.html'
);

$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $session->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    $api->setAccessToken($session->getAccessToken());

    print_r($api->me());
} else {
    $options = [
        'scope' => [
            'user-read-email',
        ],
    ];

    header('Location: ' . $session->getAuthorizeUrl($options));
    die();
}

?>
```

The code above should redirect to `index.html` (which it does) and then on the index.html page I want to show these user details but I am unsure of how to do this.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

My `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<h1>Want to see the user info here!</h1>
```